# Can i execute Kernel Function in C without nvcc compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction, cuda, nvcc

i have a question (CUDA) can i execute kernel function at C without nvcc compiler? i had this question asked and they told me that it can be done if you call Call directly from CUDA driver API with C, just is way harder.

But i want feedback from other people too.

Comment: "They" are right. It can be done if you call call directly from CUDA driver API with C, just is way harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, using the packaged nvidia-supplied toolchains, if you write CUDA code in C, the device compiler (nvcc) will be required at some point to, at a minimum, convert this C source code to valid PTX.   After that point, the *toolkit* (which includes nvcc) is not absolutely necessary.  PTX code can be JIT-compiled by the *driver* (which is separate from the toolkit) to executable code for whatever GPU is being used.  And the process of launching an appropriately written kernel (perhaps JIT-compiled from PTX) can be accomplished using only calls into the [driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#axzz35ejVOtqg).

The [runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#axzz35ejVOtqg) was created, in part, because it can simplify the process and make the overall code creation process appear to be similar to what a typical C/C++ programmer is used to.